# MVC - Rewrite URL to display domain only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I am using MVC 1.0 in .NET 3.5 Framework. I have a client who would like the URL to be displayed as **www.example.com** instead of **www.example.com/{controller}/{action}/{id}**.

1. The server that the site is hosted on is utilizing IIS 6.
2. I do not have direct access to this server.

With that in mind, can this be done?

Someone suggested using ISAPI_REWRITE. I've found a few examples but none that actually  explain correctly what needs to be done.

Alternatively, if this cannot be done throughout the site. Can it just be done on the Home page?

Below is my routing at the moment:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     // Catch all route
     routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Name
     "{lang}/{controller}" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["extension"] + "/{action}/{*values}",  // URL - ["extension"] being .aspx for IIS 6
     new { lang = "EN", controller = "Content", action = "Index" } // Defaults);
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
         "HomeIndex", // Name
         "",
         new { lang = "EN", controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Defaults);


     // Catch all route
     routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Name
     "{lang}/{controller}" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["extension"] + "/{action}/{*values}",  // URL - ["extension"] being .aspx for IIS 6
     new { lang = "EN", controller = "Content", action = "Index" } // Defaults);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Sasha. This, I am assuming, will just rewrite the Home page url, correct?

Comment: Thanks for this. Apparently, the client only wanted to have the primary landing page/Home page of the site to not have anything besides the domain. This helped a lot.

Comment: Hi, I have applied this concept but doesn't work. My requirement is same: if user type `website.com/Home` or `website.com/Home/Index`, it should `www.website.com` in Addressbar of brower. Currently it shows `www.website.com/Home/Index`. Can you please suggest me if I am missing something?

Comment: If u go by website.com will it be the same as website.com/Home/Index ?