# Is there a good way to hide the url from the user?

Tags: iis

There are three options I know of:

1. rename on the web server
2. html5 history.pushstate()
3. allegedly meta tags

I'm working on an app that relies heavily on knowing what the url is client side. I agree it's a bad design but thats another question. It is what it is.

Is there any good safe way to make the URL be just the domain name and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

I think it also depends a little bit on the technology you are using for implementation but I guess it is possible to use URL Rewriting?

Related

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx
- http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
- [MVC - Rewrite URL to display domain only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495577/mvc-rewrite-url-to-display-domain-only) [ASP.NET MVC]

Comment: i forgot to mention that we are using an isapi filter which doesn't jive with url rewriting.